# Touch Detection of UIButton added as SubView in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, uitouch

I have a scroll view with many buttons. I want to detect the touches on UIButton inside scrollView but not been able to get them. I tried by subclassing uiscrollview, and uibutton
but failed. I want to detect touches on button if user holds that button for a short time, say 2 sec. And then i want to drag the button to place where user can drag it on scroll view. Plz help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to subclass.

Try to attach to your `UIButton` a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Gesture recognizers are available from iOS 3.2 and make very easy all things related to gestures. [Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/) you can find a tutorial.

If you want to support previous versions, you have to resort to a different method:

1. add `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchDown` actions to your button;
2. in the touchDown handler start counting time (set a variable with current time);
3. in touchUp handler stop counting time; measure the difference and if is above your threshold, fire you action.

If this does not work, provide some more information as to why it doesn't, please.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But then after longPress i need to move the button on any space in scroll View as user drags it. What can do for this.

Comment: In the tutorial I linked above (http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/), go to the section "Implementing movement" and you will find working code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `tag` for each button on the `scrollView`, then like @sergio said add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`(or a uicontrolevent) to each button, so when you are setting the pages in the scrollview you could add:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

or

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *twoSecPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:)];
            [twoSecPress setMinimumPressDuration:2];
            [button addGestureRecognizer:twoSecPress];
            [twoSecPress release];
```

and in your action..

```
    -(IBAction)someAction:(id)sender{
      UIButton *button=(UIButton*)sender;
          if(button.tag==YOUR_TAG){
            //do something
    }
}
```

or

```
-(void)someAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            if ([recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                UIButton *tmpButt=(UIButton *)recognizer.view;
                NSLog(@"%d", tmpButt.tag);
    }
}
```

(obviously add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate on your .h)

Comment: I also want to move the button in scrollView to any other position by dragging it after long hold. How can i achieve this.